# How to show if a non-(skew) symmetric matrix is congruent/orthogonal equivalent to a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-congruences

I'm currently preparing for an exam, and I'm getting stuck at this seemingly straightforward question. The question is to check if the matrix $A$, given below, is congruent and/or orthogonal equivalent to a diagonal matrix.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -3 & -2 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The issue I'm having is that all theorems in the text that I'm using are aimed toward symmetric/skew-symmetric/hermitian/skew-hermitian matrix when it comes to congruent matrices.

Since this matrix $A$ has none of those properties, the only way I know to check congruence to a diagonal matrix is by using elementary row operations. Yet given the way $A$ is presented, I feel like I'm missing a straightforward solution. Is there an easier way to show the matrix is congruent and/or orthogonal equivalent to a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Every real matrix is congruent to a diagonal matrix, if by "congruent" you mean equivalent under the equivalence relation $A \mapsto MAM^T$ for arbitrary invertible $M$. The real matrices orthogonally conjugate to a diagonal matrix are precisely the normal matrices (matrices commuting with their transpose). Did you mean "conjugate" when you said "congruent"? If so, observe that $A = PDQ$ where $D$ is invertible and $PQ = I$, so in fact $Q = P^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The question does specifically state ‘congruent’. But I agree the question is a bit confusing. Is there any other way (perhaps utilizing the diagonalized form in which $A$ is presented) to quickly determine the invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=P^T D P$ or will elementary row operations be the most effective tool?